# Write a script with adjusted text

Tags: python, list, text

```
l = list(range(1, 101))
chunks = [l[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(l), 10)]
print(*chunks, sep='\r\n')
```

How can I print this list as right aligned text in 10 columns?
I've tried `'\r' right-adjust(>)` and `rjust` but both give me an error.

Comment: Your code works on my machine. The output is 10 lists which contain 10 integers in each list.

Comment: I need it to be adjusted to the right as text.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you show us your expected output?

Comment: you mean number right algined in each column? how about `,` keep or not? can you give a example output?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement: `"print this list as right aligned text in 10 columns"`.

In my understanding, you may want something like that:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
 11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
 21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
 31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
 41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
 51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
 61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
 71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
 81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
 91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

If so, you can achieve it by `rjust`, you have to convert `int` to `str` first:

```
width = 3
sep = ' '
chunks = [sep.join(map(lambda x: str(x).rjust(width), l[i:i + 10])) for i in range(0, len(l), 10)]
```

I have defined `width`, `sep`, in case you want to adjust.

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )